# Why products are disappearing from popular module after clicking on them in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.6.4.
I copied from `latest` module in opencart to create a module which shows popular products.
In catalog side's controller i replaced the code below

```
$data = array(
            'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit']
        );

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

by

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getPopularProducts($setting['limit']);
```

and ofcourse did a find-replace of `latest/popular`

Everything is working ok, But if i click on a product of the `popular module` to see the details of it and then come back to the layout where the `popular module` is set, that product is being disappeared.

Whats wrong am i doing ?

### EDIT

I'm using default model which stays in `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`. Code of `getPopularProducts()` is as below

```
public function getPopularProducts($limit) {
        $product_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.viewed, p.date_added DESC LIMIT " . (int)$limit);

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {         
            $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        }

        return $product_data;
    }
```

and the `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/popula.tpl` is as below

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-product">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT 2

Here is the full code of the controller `popular`

```
<?php
class ControllerModulePopular extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('module/popular');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $this->data['products'] = array();


       $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getPopularProducts($setting['limit']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
            } else {
                $image = false;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = $result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'      => $image,
                'name'       => $result['name'],
                'price'      => $price,
                'special'    => $special,
                'rating'     => $rating,
                'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
            );
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/popular.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/popular.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/popular.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe sharing a code from the model (method `getPopularProducts`) would be vital...

Comment: @shadyyx It is the default model and function come with opencart. I'm using opencart 1.5.6.4, but the function is kinda standard for 1.5x versions i think. But if you still need the function/method i can provide

Comment: OK, what is happening probably is update of the `viewed` DATETIME value - are you sure you have correct date and time set on your server? I think it is setting some older date (or time - more probable because of incorrect timezone) and since the `getPopularProducts` query is doing `ORDER BY p.viewed DESC` the product is pushed further in the results and because of `LIMIT` it is then not listed at all...

Comment: How to check: mark down current date and time. Mark down the `datetime` value of `product.viewed` for your desired product you are going to open the detail of. Open up the detail page of that product and now check again the value of `product.viewed` column. Is it updated and set correctly? Very common problem is different timezone setting between PHP and MySQL servers

Comment: @shadyyx product.viewed updating properly, but i see that the most viewed product(13 times) is not even being listed as most popular. Should't the query be ordered by ASC instead of DESC?

Comment: Mmmm, I think I misunderstood the meaning of the `viewed` property. I thought it's datetime, but it's just INT counter how many times was the product viewed :-D OK then. From what you have posted and said so far I am little bit suspicious that we are not looking at the right code... Could you post here also the controller for this popular products module?

Comment: @shadyyx , i have added the full code of the controller popular